# How to correctly add a square grid inside a polygon using turfjs?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, turfjs

So i'm currently playing around with turfjs. And i'm trying to add a squaregrid inside a polygon.

So here's the code

```
var triangleCoords = [
  { lat: 25.774, lng: -80.19 },
  { lat: 18.466, lng: -66.118 },
  { lat: 32.321, lng: -64.757 },
  { lat: 25.774, lng: -80.19 }
];

// Construct the polygon.
var bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
  paths: triangleCoords,
  strokeColor: "#FF0000",
  strokeOpacity: 0.8,
  strokeWeight: 2,
  fillColor: "#FF0000",
  fillOpacity: 0.35
});
bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);

const geoJSON = {
  type: 'Polygon',
  coordinates: []
};

// convert to bermudaTriangle path to geojson
for (let point of bermudaTriangle.getPath().getArray()) {
  geoJSON.coordinates.push([point.lat(), point.lng()]);
}

const feature = turf.feature(geoJSON);

const bbox = turf.bbox(feature);

// ERROR: this one's showing Infinity values
console.table(bbox);
const grid = turf.squareGrid(bbox, 50, {
  units: "miles",
  mask: feature
});

map.data.addGeoJson(grid);
```

and looking at the console, it shows Infinity values for bbox as commented on the code.

I've added a link for the code
https://codepen.io/chan-dev/pen/yrdRoM

Comment: GeoJSON is usually `[longitude, latitude]` for coordinates.

Comment: @geocodezip I've already switched the two but still no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`geoJSON` is not a valid [GeoJSON object for Polygon](http://wiki.geojson.org/GeoJSON_draft_version_6#Polygon) in the provided example, that's the reason why `turf.bbox` returns invalid result. GeoJSON for polygon could be constructed via `turf.polygon` like this:

```
var triangleCoords = [
  { lat: 25.774, lng: -80.19 },
  { lat: 18.466, lng: -66.118 },
  { lat: 32.321, lng: -64.757 },
  { lat: 25.774, lng: -80.19 }
];

var data = triangleCoords.map(coord => {
  return [coord.lng, coord.lat];
});
var geojson = turf.polygon([data]);
```

and bounding box calculated like this:

```
const bbox = turf.bbox(geojson);
```

[**Modified** CodePen](https://codepen.io/vgrem/pen/WWqLpP)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Already got the idea. I didn't notice there's a turf.polygon method. 
I think the only thing i need to do is is rotate it in the same angle the same with the polygon.

Any idea how to rotate the grid at the same angle as the polygon?